# CRM 2011 - Export Translations Issue - LocLabels Issue in Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon-control

I recently have some problems when exporting the translations of an entity. At first I thought that the problem was lying much deeper than just the ribbon.. But with some testing, I found out that it were my LocLabels that caused the problem.  The buttons itself (+ in-line translations) are working correctly!  I define the 3 used languages ("Dutch", "French" and "English") in my Ribbon-XML and everything seems to be translated correctly.  But when I want to export the translations for that particular entity, nothing seems to happen...

If instead of "$LocLabels:", I just use plain text, everything seems to work and I can export the translations for that entity.

The XML looks as following:

**CustomAction XML snippet**

```
  <CustomAction Id="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.ave_student.MainTab.Groups._children" Sequence="115">
    <CommandUIDefinition>
      <Group Id="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Group" Command="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Command" Title="$LocLabels:Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Title" Sequence="85" Template="Mscrm.Templates.3.3">
        <Controls Id="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Controls">
          <Button Id="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Button.A" Command="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Button.A.Command" Sequence="10" LabelText="$LocLabels:Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Button.A.LabelText" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Button.A.LabelText" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Button.A.Description" TemplateAlias="o1" Image16by16="$webresource:ave_eid16x16" Image32by32="$webresource:ave_eid32x32" />
        </Controls>
      </Group>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CustomAction>
```

**LocLabels XML snippet**

```
<LocLabels>
  <LocLabel Id="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Title">
    <Titles>
      <Title languagecode="1043" description="HC" />
      <Title languagecode="1036" description="HC" />
  <Title languagecode="1033" description="HC" />
    </Titles>
  </LocLabel>
  <LocLabel Id="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Button.A.Description">
    <Titles>
      <Title languagecode="1043" description="Read eID" />
      <Title languagecode="1036" description="Read eID" />
  <Title languagecode="1033" description="Read eID" />
    </Titles>
  </LocLabel>
  <LocLabel Id="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Button.A.LabelText">
    <Titles>
      <Title languagecode="1043" description="Read eID" />
      <Title languagecode="1036" description="Read eID" />
  <Title languagecode="1033" description="Read eID" />
    </Titles>
  </LocLabel>
  <LocLabel Id="Sample.Grid.ave_student.CustomGroup.Button.A.ToolTipDescription">
    <Titles>
      <Title languagecode="1043" description="Read eID" />
      <Title languagecode="1036" description="Read eID" />
      <Title languagecode="1033" description="Read eID" />
    </Titles>
  </LocLabel>
<LocLabels>
```

Is there someone who encountered the same problems as us?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to export the translations?  Does it throw an error or does it just not include the translations in the exported XML or does it not do anything as you suggest?  Also, do you have the language packs for all of the languages you mentioned installed?

Comment: Nothing happens... There is for example no entry in the "Event Viewer".  We have all "Language Packs" installed for the used languages. We really don't know what we are doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.  It were particular "Loclabels" from a managed solutions that caused the problem.  For some reason the loclabels of the managed solution entered in my normal "customization" of the entity and that's why I couldn't export the translations.  It gave me an "Duplicate" translation error.  After removing the loclabel, I was able to export/import the translations.